# Laptop LCD bottom edge horizontal 1 pixel's strip flickers by showing the exact colors showing top edge horizontal pixels

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, hp-pavilion

After a few seconds of windows startup, my laptop's lcd's bottom edge horizontal pixel strip of height around 1 or 2 pixels start flickering by flashing the exact colors on top horizonal edge of lcd at the moment. If I lower the refresh rate from 144hz to 60hz it becomes less noticeable but keeps happening. Sometimes in flickering it completely shows black color. Flickers in a time pattern, like flashes after 2 or 3 second period.

I have tried: Updating, Uninstalling, reinstalling the display drivers. Reconnecting the display cable from motherboard side. Use DISM. Pressing/applying pressure around bottom of lcd.

Nothing of above did anything.

Comment: I could think of a couple of things but at this point you need to get the machine serviced

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, can you please advise what type of issue it can be, its almost as new laptop.

Comment: Could be the screen itself.  Could be the connector on the screen.  Those are the two most likely

Comment: Is the resolution set to the native LCD resolution?

Comment: Yes Its set to native 1920 x 1080